# what TensorFlow hash_bucket_size matters

Tags: tensorflow

I am creating a DNNclassifier with sparse columns. The training data looks like this,

```
samples        col1                         col2          price label
  eg1    [[0,1,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,3,...]    [[0,0,4,5,0,...]    5.2    0
  eg2    [0,0,...]                     [0,0,...]            0     1
  eg3    [0,0,...]]                    [0,0,...]            0     1
```

The following snippet can run successfully,

```
import tensorflow as tf

sparse_feature_a = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket('col1', 3, dtype=tf.int32)
sparse_feature_b = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket('col2', 1000, dtype=tf.int32)

sparse_feature_a_emb = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(sparse_id_column=sparse_feature_a, dimension=2)
sparse_feature_b_emb = tf.contrib.layers.embedding_column(sparse_id_column=sparse_feature_b, dimension=2)
feature_c = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('price')

estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(
    feature_columns=[sparse_feature_a_emb, sparse_feature_b_emb, feature_c],
    hidden_units=[5, 3],
    n_classes=2,
    model_dir='./tfTmp/tfTmp0')

# Input builders
def input_fn_train(): # returns x, y (where y represents label's class index).
    features = {'col1': tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 1], [0, 5], [0, 7], [0, 9]],
                                  values=[1, 2, 1, 3],
                                  dense_shape=[3, int(250e6)]),
                'col2': tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 2], [0, 3]],
                                    values=[4, 5],
                                    dense_shape=[3, int(100e6)]),
                        'price': tf.constant([5.2, 0, 0])}
    labels = tf.constant([0, 1, 1])
    return features, labels

estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train, steps=100)
```

However, I have a question from this sentence,

```
sparse_feature_a = tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket('col1', 3, dtype=tf.int32)
```

where 3 means **hash_bucket_size=3**, but this sparse tensor includes 4 non-zero values,

```
'col1': tf.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 1], [0, 5], [0, 7], [0, 9]],
                              values=[1, 2, 1, 3],
                              dense_shape=[3, int(250e6)])
```

It seems *has_bucket_size* does nothing here. No matter how many non-zero values you have in your sparse tensor, you just need to set it with an integer > 1 and it works correctly.

I know my understanding may not be right. Could anyone explain how **has_bucket_size** works? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

`hash_bucket_size` works by taking the original indices, hashing them into a space of the specified size, and using the hashed indices as features.

This means you can specify your model before knowing the full range of possible indices, at the cost of some indices maybe colliding.

Comment: Thanks! Now I think if one can guess a number covering the whole range of the real data then it is perfect. If one guesses a number smaller than expected, it will also work but may cause unsure behaviour.